# Cumulative calculation/ Calculation based on previous row data in Oracle 19c

Tags: sql, oracle, cumulative-sum, oracle19c

How to implement cumulative calculations on a column to calculate a value based on data in same column but previous row?

*For instance: Considering below table and records*

**Data -**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( DT DATE, NAME VARCHAR2(10), AMOUNT NUMBER(10,3));

insert into TEST values ( to_date( '01-jan-2021'), 'apple', 198.95 );
insert into TEST values ( to_date( '02-jan-2021'), 'apple', 6.15 );
insert into TEST values ( to_date( '03-jan-2021'), 'apple', 4.65 );
insert into TEST values ( to_date( '04-jan-2021'), 'apple', 20.85 );
insert into TEST values ( to_date( '01-jan-2021'), 'banana', 80.5 );
insert into TEST values ( to_date( '02-jan-2021'), 'banana', 9.5 );
insert into TEST values ( to_date( '03-jan-2021'), 'banana', 31.65 );
```

**Desired Output:**

```
DT          NAME    AMOUNT  CALC
---------------------------------
1-Jan-21    apple   198.95  39.79
2-Jan-21    apple   6.15    33.062
3-Jan-21    apple   4.65    27.380
4-Jan-21    apple   20.85   26.074
.
.
.
1-Jan-21    banana  80.5    16.1
2-Jan-21    banana  9.5     14.78
3-Jan-21    banana  31.65   18.14
.
.
.
```

I need to write a query to obtain CALC for each record (grouped by NAME) based on below formula:

`((CALC of prev day record * 4)+ AMOUNT of current record )/ 5`

```
i.e for APPLE 
for 1-jan-21, CALC = ((0*4)+198.95)/5 = 39.79 -------> since it is 1st record, have taken 0 as CALC of prev day record
for 2-jan-21, CALC = ((39.79*4)+6.15)/5= 33.062 -----> prev CALC is considered from 1-jan-21 - 39.79 and 6.15 from current row
for 3-jan-21, CALC = ((33.062*4)+4.65)/5= 27.380 and so on

For BANANA
1-jan-21, CALC = ((0*4)+80.5)/5=16.1
1-jan-21, CALC = ((16.1*4)+9.5)/5=14.78 
etc
```

I have tried using lag, with, join etc and also looked upon internet but unable to arrive at a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the successive rows with amounts: a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, ...

Then the `calc` value for the successive rows is:

1. a<sub>1</sub> × (4<sup>0</sup> ÷ 5<sup>1</sup>)
2. a<sub>1</sub> × (4<sup>1</sup> ÷ 5<sup>2</sup>) + a<sub>2</sub> × (4<sup>0</sup> ÷ 5<sup>1</sup>)
3. a<sub>1</sub> × (4<sup>2</sup> ÷ 5<sup>3</sup>) + a<sub>2</sub> × (4<sup>1</sup> ÷ 5<sup>2</sup>) + a<sub>3</sub> × (4<sup>0</sup> ÷ 5<sup>1</sup>)
4. ...

You can use this (and the fact that your data has successive days) to calculate the progression with the query:

```sql
SELECT t2.dt,
       t2.name,
       t2.amount,
       SUM(POWER(4/5, t2.dt - t1.dt) * t1.amount / 5) AS calc
FROM   test t1
       INNER JOIN test t2
       ON (t1.name = t2.name AND t1.dt <= t2.dt)
GROUP BY
       t2.dt,
       t2.name,
       t2.amount
ORDER BY
       t2.name,
       t2.dt;
```

You could also use the `MODEL` clause:

```sql
SELECT dt,
       name,
       amount,
       calc
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY dt) AS rn
  FROM   test t
)
MODEL
  PARTITION BY (name)
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES ( dt, amount, 0 AS calc)
  RULES (
    calc[1] = amount[1]/5,
    calc[rn>1] = (amount[cv(rn)] + 4*calc[cv(rn)-1])/5
  )
```

Which, for your sample data, both output:

> | DT | NAME | AMOUNT | CALC |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 01-JAN-21 | apple | 198.95 | 39.79 |
> | 02-JAN-21 | apple | 6.15 | 33.062 |
> | 03-JAN-21 | apple | 4.65 | 27.3796 |
> | 04-JAN-21 | apple | 20.85 | 26.07368 |
> | 01-JAN-21 | banana | 80.5 | 16.1 |
> | 02-JAN-21 | banana | 9.5 | 14.78 |
> | 03-JAN-21 | banana | 31.65 | 18.154 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8629a49d04ad40c4f3a9481812c1914e)*